# Debugging 400/400 = -858993460

Tags: c++, c, debugging

[image]

Just confused, why is not mL = 1?

Comment: Because it's not initialized yet? What happens if you step once more?

Comment: That assignment hasn't yet run; the breakpoint on that line indicates that the debugger should stop just *before* that code. Step again and you'll see the correct value.

Comment: Yeah step once more and you will get it as 1

Comment: the bigger question is...why 400/400?? :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I had a equation there with the output 1. Changed it to 400/400 for simplicity.

Comment: Why is this tagged C and C++ ? You should know in which language you are writing your programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual studio treats `int mL = 400/400` as two step process.

First step would be allocating memory in stack. So, you see a garbage value. Press F10/F11 (step once more) you should see 1.

-858993460 translates to 0xCCCCCCCC which is a bit pattern used by Microsoft compilers to detect buffer overruns and to initialize an empty stack.Some more details here - [softwareverify.com/memory-bit-patterns.php](http://softwareverify.com/memory-bit-patterns.php)

Comment: It is *not* a garbage value, -858993460 has a well defined meaning.  That it appears more than once in the OP's screenshot is also not an accident.  Convert it to hex to see that it is special.

Comment: and this value often appears in debug mode. It helps debugging in many situations

Comment: It is nothing special. It is 0xCCCCCCCC. This bit pattern is often used by MS compilers. I Couldn't find it officially in MFC or Win32 but I guess this could help - http://www.softwareverify.com/memory-bit-patterns.php

Comment: [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)